# error: failed linking file resources. without any message to error

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I got this error

`error: failed linking file resources.`

But with no info about error
also, **gradle tasks** was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to **use**

`./gradlew build --stacktrace`

with **terminal** this will **build app** and will show your **error**